# Using fetch() and getting 'Undefined' when calling a value from the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs, fetch-api

I am able to `console.log` the JSON response from fetch() and it shows that I am in fact receiving the JSON response from the API URL.

This is the code that will `console.log` the JSON response without an issue (please note that I've ommited res.render() from this code while I am sorting the JSON issue):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    fetch(url)
    .then(function(res){
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        ico = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(ico); // Logs the JSON data without issue
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
});
```

This is a snippet of that JSON response from the requested URL:

```
    {
       "ico": {
          "live": [{
             "name": "ViMarket",
             "image": "https://icowatchlist.com/logos/vimarket.png",
             "description": "A 3D marketplace that allows users to create and share virtual reality VR experiences ViMarket promises to bring about a muchneeded breakthrough in the global ecommerce ecosystem",
             "website_link": "https://api.icowatchlist.com/public/v1/url/vimarket",
             "icowatchlist_url": "https://icowatchlist.com/ico/vimarket",
             "start_time": "2017-12-07 00:00:00",
             "end_time": "2018-01-31 00:00:00",
             "timezone": "UTC+0"
          }, {

         "name": "Pocketinns",
         "image": "https://icowatchlist.com/logos/pocketinns.png",
         "description": "The worlds first decentralized blockchain driven marketplace ecosystem",
         "website_link": "https://api.icowatchlist.com/public/v1/url/pocketinns",
         "icowatchlist_url": "https://icowatchlist.com/ico/pocketinns",
         "start_time": "2018-01-15 10:00:00",
         "end_time": "2018-01-31 10:00:00",
         "timezone": "UTC--3"
      }]}
}
```

My issue began when I was started having a problem using the JSON data that I passed into an EJS template, so I tried to `console.log` a key-value pair from the JSON data to see to see if there was an issue with it. This showed me that I was getting an 'undefined' value anytime I wanted to call a key-value pair.

Here is the code snippet that produces that issue:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    fetch(url)
    .then(function(res){
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        let ico = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(ico.live.name); // Returns 'undefined'
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
});
```

I am confused as to why it will output anything other than 'undefined' when I specifically call a value. I am sure there is something I am not doing correctly.

Here is the full snippet:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
        fetch(url)
        .then(function(res){
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){
            let ico = JSON.stringify(data);
            res.render('pages/index', { ico: ico });
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    });
```

Why can I `console.log(ico)` and get the entire JSON response without issue, but when I want to `console.log(ico.live.name)`, I get 'undefined'? From what I can tell from my `console.log`s, I am passing the entire JSON response into my EJS template, but I am failing to properly access the values in the JSON response from the Javascript in my EJS template.

Comment: shouldn't it be `ico.live[0].name`?

Comment: if you're stringifying the data, you can't use the properties like it's an object.let ico = JSON.stringify(data); console.log(ico.live.name) .live and .name aren't propterties of the string ico

Comment: that gives me a TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: try `let result = JSON.stringify(data);
res.render('pages/index', { ico: result.ico });`

Comment: You should unwrap the root elemenet {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unnecessarily transforming the JSON data to a JavaScript Object and then back to JSON text format again, trying to reference Object properties on it.

The `return res.json()` already transforms the JSON response to a JavaScript object, so you should remove your `JSON.stringify` if you want to access that data.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => res.render('pages/index', { ico: data.ico }))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500); // Make sure you close the connection on an error!
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative! Everything is working as intended now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the properties of the object, don't stringify the data.

```
.then(function(ico){
    //let ico = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(ico.live.name); 
    // you can then assign the properties to variables and
    // use them
    let liveName = ico.live.name;
    // or, if you need that as a string, use stringify
    let name = JSON.stringify(ico.name);
});
```